# ApplePay canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard Promise returns false

Tags: javascript, safari, applepay, applepayjs

ApplePay **canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard** Promise returns false on a Mac Safari, but true on iPhone Safari. **canMakePayments** returns true on both. I'm using a sandbox Apple developer account with test credit cards that Apple provided. Any idea why **canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard** returns false on a Mac Safari?

```
if (window.ApplePaySession) {
    // I'm not posting actual merchantIdentifier due to security reasons
    var merchantIdentifier = 'my unique identifier';
    var promise = ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard(merchantIdentifier);
    promise.then(function (canMakePayments) {
        if (canMakePayments)
        // For some reason false on Mac Safari
    }); 
}
```

Comment: On you Mac, your country might not be in the list of countries which support Apple Pay.

Comment: I have it set up for USA

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that the test credit cards in the Wallet did not have the billing address set.  It appears that billing address is required in order to be considered active and usable on the web, although I can find no documentation that indicates this.

Comment: Thanks, that was missing on the sandbox tester user docs on Apple.